# Encrypted URL does not recognized all characters

Tags: c#, url

I have an Encrypted URL which looks like:

```
http://server:5447/PM/WebPage/KO/AngefragtePM.aspx?eventID=no0w7CFJIOIsbtPghLWbHg==
```

My Problem is the " == " at the end of the URL.

The Hyperlink looks like:

[http://www.test.de:5447/PM/WebPage/KOP/AngefragtePM.aspx?eventID=no0w7CFJIOIsbtPghLWbHg](http://www.test.de:5447/PM/WebPage/KOP/AngefragtePM.aspx?eventID=no0w7CFJIOIsbtPghLWbHg==)==

The Hyperlink does not recognize the " == ". So i cant open the URL.

Is there a way to parse this to a correct URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to url encode the value if you want this to be a valid query string parameter:

```
eventID=no0w7CFJIOIsbtPghLWbHg%3D%3D
```

So modify the code that generates this hyperlink so that it properly url encodes the parameter.

Comment: thanks Darin. The Problem is that i generate the URL dynamically. The eventID can be different. So the Encrypted eventID looks different ever time.

Comment: Sure, I didn't say the contrary. All you have to do is to URL encode the value once you dynamically generate it. Otherwise you are simply getting an invalid URL.